# How to fit a div with fixed dimension inside another div without altering styling of the div we want to fit?

Tags: html, css

My case is a little specific. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-ub5scm?file=index.html)

```html
<div style="background-color: yellow; border: thin solid black; width: 215px">
  <div style="background-color: red; border: thin solid black; width: 50%">
    <div style="width: 100%">
      I need to fit the below div inside this div. Ignore styling of this text.

      <!-- Below div is immutable -->
      <div
        style="
          background-color: green;
          border: thin solid black;
          width: 10cm;
          height: 4cm;
        "
      >
        Fixed styling for this div. This div is later converted to an image of
        this dimesion for printing. So we are not allowed to alter any css of
        this div.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

What I need was something like this:

```html
<div style="background-color: yellow; border: thin solid black; width: 215px">
  <div style="background-color: red; border: thin solid black; width: 50%">
    <div
      style="
        width: 100%;

        scale: 28.5%;          
        margin: -88px -39px;   
      "
    >
      I need to fit the below div inside this div. Ignore styling of this text.

      <!-- Below div is immutable -->
      <div
        style="
          background-color: green;
          border: thin solid black;
          width: 10cm;
          height: 4cm;
        "
      >
        Fixed styling for this div. This div is later converted to an image of
        this dimesion for printing. So we are not allowed to alter any css of
        this div.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

But this is a very brittle solution. (if I change the outer div (yellow) width or the inner div (green) width or dimensions, it completely breaks)

Comment: sounds like an X-Y problem to me. Why are you not allowed to change the dimension because of printing? You can declare extra styling just for printing (`@media print`).

Comment: It is not that window.print, It is thermal-print - using webUSB. So the @media print not applicable here.

Comment: @Wajahath Are you allowed to use JS to calculate the size of the red, and give it to the green on page load? Are there other conditions you have to work within?

Comment: @Bjorn.B Yes. That is what I ended up doing. Created a wrapper div and calculated dimensions and margins and applied. So far, it works good.